# How to create EJB 3 application with WAS7

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, websphere-7

I want to create EJB project to call to all the other projects.

**Requirement**

1. Create the EAR project that contains EJB module (Project A).
2. Create two different EAR projects (Let say Project B and C) and call the EJB module (Project A). I don’t want to add Project A as deployment assembly in Project B and C.

I’m using WebSphere 7.0
Please can someone tell me this is possible or not and If it is possible share the idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create dependency on Project A directly, you can only create EJB client jar for Project A, put your interfaces and shared classes there and make Projects B and C dependent on this EJB client project.

To create client project you should be able to right click your EJB Project then select Java EE > Create EJB Client jar